# Zoom capability in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, zooming, pdfbox

`PDFBox` indicates zooming is capable using `PDPageXYZDestination`, however I'm really struggling to make it work. An example would be helpful, including where to make calls to this class.

The following was posted in another thread, however there's no indicator of exactly where to put this code:

```
PDPageXYZDestination dest = new PDPageXYZDestination();
dest.setPageNumber(0);
dest.setZoom(1);
dest.setTop(new Float(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER.getHeight()).intValue());
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
action.setDestination(dest);    
document.getDocumentCatalog().setOpenAction(action);
```

If you have a complete example it would be truly helpful.

Comment: Here's some complete example code from the source: http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox-examples/1.8.8/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/GoToSecondBookmarkOnOpen.java/?v=source

Comment: Thanks for the link, however that code won't actually allow me to zoom in or out of a page after it's open in PDFReader. Have a more refined example anywhere?

Comment: What do you want to do? Have this destination from an outline entry? (Also known as "bookmarks"?) If so, see the CreateBookmarks example: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/branches/1.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreateBookmarks.java  there replace the PDPageFitWidthDestination with PDPageXYZDestination.

Comment: The outcome I'm chasing is to open the PDF and view the first page full size. From a menu, allow me to zoom in or zoom out

Comment: Sounds like real work (too much for me now). You'd need to create annotations that look like a menu, and use PDAnnotationLink with PDPageXYZDestination as destination. See this example on how t use PDAnnotationLink  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/branches/1.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/Annotation.java

Comment: Work it is. been at it for days, no success yet. I'll have a look at your PDAnnotationLink example.

Comment: Good luck! If you need more help, either open a new, more specific question; if you need more unspecific help with some back and forth Q & A, subscribe & ask to the PDFBox user mailing list. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/